# iothub-explorer has time lag after start showing device to cloud messages

Tags: azure-iot-hub

I installed iothub-explorer with npm (as far as i can remember). Since the beginning, I notice a significant time lag (several seconds till over a minute) after starting before the messages appear the first time. It occurs almost every time, but more often and more severe, if I haven't run it for a long time or restarted the computer.
After the first time lag, all messages that have been sent since starting iothub-eplorer arrive in a bulk and the next messages are displayed in real time.
The problem is that I can not test the programs on my device if I can not rely on the iothub-explorer (showing me the incoming messages).

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04, my nodejs version is v4.2.6, npm version 3.5.2 and my itohub-explorer version is 1.1.12.

Please request additional information as neccessary since I'm not so experienced with nodejs and don't know what information is relevant.

Update:
I changed from the low-level API to the normal API (with thread in background). Now it seems to work really well, the messages arrive on time. But still, before that, the IOTHUB_CLIENT_CONFIRMATION_OK ack arrived soon after the messages were sent on the device, despite the delayed messages in iothub-explorer.

Comment: Can you start iothub-eplorer before you run the program to send messages?

Comment: I just did that. The first three messages cam in bulk, the rest normally. But I had started the iothub-explorer several times before.

Answer (score 0):

It is by-designed because it receives from serval event hub partitions concurrently. For this, you can check the [source code](https://github.com/Azure/iothub-explorer/blob/master/iothub-explorer-monitor-events.js).

There is a workaround that you can utilize event hub. Then you can send to one specified partition:

```
CreatePartitionedSender(partition)
```

And receive only from this partition:

```
eventHubClient.GetDefaultConsumerGroup().CreateReceiver(partition, DateTime.UtcNow)
```

Note that azure iot hub and event hub are both **near** real-time.